# Compile templateFile with scope in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a function for a type of list, that will take the item in a scope that you clicked on, and render it in a modal (like clicking on an article in a category, and getting the full article in a modal).

The following code is located in a page controller, and not a directive. I would later on like to move this code over to my Modal service, to more easily build modal templates.

I can retrive the template from $templateCache, and render it in the modal:

```
app.controller('FlowController', function($log, $scope, $compile, $templateCache, Modal) {
  $scope.modal = function(){
    var template = $templateCache.get('/frontend/flow/partials/classifiedModal.html');
    Modal.dialog(template);
  };
});
```

Now, I want to combine that template with a scope:

```
app.controller('FlowController', function($log, $scope, $compile, $templateCache, Modal) {
  $scope.modal = function(index){
    var template = $templateCache.get('/frontend/flow/partials/classifiedModal.html');
    var compiled = $compile(template)($scope.classifieds[index]);
    Modal.large(compiled);
  };
});
```

This keeps giving me an error `Undefined is not a function`

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at textInterpolateLinkFn (http://localhost:3001/angular/angular.js:6975:23)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3001/angular/angular.js:6711:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3001/angular/angular.js:6105:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3001/angular/angular.js:6108:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3001/angular/angular.js:6001:30)
    at Scope.$scope.modal (http://localhost:3001/flow/flow.js:54:47)
    at Parser.functionCall (http://localhost:3001/angular/angular.js:10846:21)
    at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://localhost:3001/angular/angular.js:19133:17)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3001/angular/angular.js:12701:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3001/angular/angular.js:12799:23) {{title}}
```

Comment: Is $scope.classifieds[index] actually a scope?

Comment: what is actually undefined ? you may have forgot to inject $compile service as a dependency

Comment: question updated for clarification.